# Vim's global command with patterns joined by comma

Tags: vim, command, ex

From the docs, the syntax of the [`:global`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) command is:

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
                        Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
                        lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

I've also come across such usages of `:g`:

```
:g/apples/+1,/peaches/ s/^/# /g
:g/start/+1,$ sort n
```

Does `/apples/+1,/peaches/` here belong to the `{pattern}`? Where is this syntax documented?

Comment: Can I ask where did you see that usages?

Comment: @seuling: Vim Tips Wiki, for example. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges).

Comment: Oh thanks! I see. glad you find the answer. Anyway, why I can't tag your name?

Comment: @seuling: Check this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260761/244297) on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found an explanation for this very usage of `:global` in [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges):

```
:g/apples/,/peaches/ s/^/# /g
    Insert "# " at the start of each line in all identified blocks. 
    :g/apples/ identifies each line containing "apples". 
    In each such line, .,/peaches/ s/^/# /g is executed 
    (the . is assumed; it means the current line, where "apples" occurs).
```

So `,/peaches/` here defines a range for the *substitution command*. The somewhat confusing part (which i didn't find mentioned in the docs) is that the initial `'.'` is optional in a range. Adding it makes the command more obvious:

```
:g/apples/.,/peaches/s/^/# /g
```